# star rating in rails with ajaxful-rating / prototype vs jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

It must be late because I can't figure out what the best way to go here.

I found that the ajaxful-rating gem is probably what I need, and I really want to get going, but then I am confused by 2 other gema which are JQuery implementation of Ajaxful-rating:

http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-star-rating-rails
and
https://github.com/mbchandar/jqrating

... well I don't have enough background to understand what this means... but something tells me that there is something about using JQuery vs Prototype. So I am assuming that ajaxful-rating may be using prototype (?).

Since Rails 3.1 uses JQuery by default, and knowing that I am also using Twitter Bootstrap which uses JQuery and I am just worried that if install ajax-ful-rating I may be messing my current environment.

QUESTION 1: Is ajaxful-rating using prototype?

QUESTION 2: Should I worry about it? or can I just install it or will I run into problems?

QUESTION 3: Are jquery implementations of ajaxful-rating a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest that better if you use `'letsrate'` gem instead `ajaxful-rating`.

Have a look on the following link. 
https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate

Answer (score 0):

Try, in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'ajaxful_rating', :git => 'git://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating.git', :branch => "rails3"
```

It is the Rails 3 version.

Letsrate is an okay gem, but very underpowered in terms of its helpers, compared to ajaxful-rating.